# Refreshing FB Access Token with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

For context I am trying to build a small microsite to pull social media insights from Facebook. I am looking to build a Django backend and React front end.

I would like to implement FB login with the Javascript SDK since according to the docs this refreshes the access token each time a FB call is made using the SDK.

I have a very simple login script taken from FB official docs which literally just logs in the user and then outputs the list of accounts the user has access to.

The issue is that, despite refreshing the page (and therefore performing an API request) the data expiration date doesn’t extend (it still displays the date of first login).

Is anyone familiar with the Javascript SDK and whether this is normal behaviour?

```
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
  console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {  // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      testAPI();

      FB.getAuthResponse(function(response){
      console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
      });

    } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this webpage.';
    }
  }


  function checkLoginState() {               // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // See the onlogin handler
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID_GOES_HERE',
      cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
      xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
      version    : 'v13.0'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
    statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
    });
  };

  function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me/accounts',
    function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      
    });
  }


function logout_js_user(){
FB.logout(function(response) {
   // Person is now logged out
});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/#servers) does refresh the Token, but not on every Page call. It only refreshes the Token when it is not valid anymore. That is why the expiration data does not change.

You can can a more accurate status with the second parameter of the function set to `true`, but be aware that this might affect performance:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
}, true);
```

> If you call FB.getLoginStatus on every page load, be careful not to
> set this parameter for each as it will significantly increase the
> number of requests to Facebook's servers, and thus decrease the
> performance of your application.

Side note: ou can use `FB.login` to make the login less complicated (in my opinion) - here's an old but still valid article about that: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Thanks, @andyrandy. Understood, re it doesn’t refresh each day. Do you know when it refreshes the data access at all? Does it just wait till it’s expired and then auto refresh it on the first api call after expiry?

Comment: It refreshes at least when it expired and you call getLoginStatus again. it does not refresh on regular api calls afaik, so you need to use getLoginStatus on page load.